# Symfony Make Entity issue

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony4

Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. DeliciousPuppy):

> test

created: src/Entity/Test.php
created: src/Repository/TestRepository.php

Entity generated! Now let's add some fields!
You can always add more fields later manually or by re-running this command.

New property name (press  to stop adding fields):

> name

In MakeEntity.php line 332:

Undefined class constant 'JSON_ARRAY'

make:entity [-a|--api-resource] [--regenerate] [--overwrite] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  []

I have tried after downgrade and upgrade doctrine version but did not get solution.

Comment: Interesting error.  I installed a fresh 4.4 app (PHP 8.2) and make:entity worked fine.  Type::JSON_ARRAY has been deprecated and the bit of code that still uses it actually tries to remove the definition.  I sort of think you have your versions messed in composer.json?  Might try installing a new 4.4 app like I did and if the error goes away then compare the new composer.json with your legacy one.  I suppose you could also just comment out a few lines near the end of MakeEntity.php and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Add package on your project by using composer

composer require doctrine/dbal:2.13.6

Symfony 4.4 Entity with commands working fine

Comment: Right, it's working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).